# MS Outlook 2007 ~ VBA to apply a rule to text in Attachment

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments, rules, outlook-2010

Is it possible (via VBA or other method) to apply a rule (eg. 'Move Email to Folder X') to an email based just on text in an attachment on that email.

I receive emails with XML attachments manually open them to find a specific date inside. I then file the emails into different folders based on this date.

I wpuld like to automate this process. The XML file has a field called   1/1/2013 . I would like the macro to open this attachment/ extract the date value / close the attachment, then move the email into a folder based on that date. (nothing too fancy...eg, I will initially create 12 folders based on each month)

I successfully use built in 'Rules' when the email body has the text I use to sort, but I need something specifically for attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, [KB 306108](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306108) has a sample script which can be run as a rule action (where you can do further processing).

Comment: that link seems to be broken.I'm getting a 'runtime error' paeg when I try open it. Not sure if it's a stackoverfow issue or an incorrect link. Can you check it ? cheers - Marcus

Comment: The link is http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306108 and I just checked it and it's ok from here.

Comment: Thanks @James-snell . When I click the link or paste it into internet explorer, it returns an error. However, it opens fine in Chrome!!  My question was more directed towards using data in an attachment to apply to a rule. I can create the basic rules through vba already. I need the code/tips on extracting info thats in an attachment on an email.

Comment: That sounds weird as I use IE (chrome is blocked on this machine, which is harder to do than it sounds given its attempts to bypass code/data separation...)  But anyway, Item has an Attachments collection which you can then save the attachment to a file and process as normal.  I'll do you an edit with a sample.